# Counting binary strings of length n with no two adjacent 1's

Tags: combinatorics

I need to calculate the total number of possible binary strings of length $n$ with no two adjacent 1's.

```
Eg.
for n = 3
f(n) = 5
000,001,010,100,101
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: $f(n)=F_{n+2}$ where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number. Have also a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_coding

Comment: Permutation is probably not the best word to use here.  It appears you are counting *binary strings* (or finite sequences of 0's and 1's) "with no two adjacent 1's".  Permutation is often used by mathematicians to describe arrangements (or rearrangements) of distinct values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:**
Use a recurrence relation. What if the string with $k$ bits starts with a 1, how many possibilities gives this for strings with $k+1$ bits? If the string with $k$ bits starts with a 0, how many possibilities gives this for strings with $k+1$ bits?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense and I could prove it to be Fibonacci series. I didn't know about Fibonacci coding earlier, otherwise it would have been obvious to me.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematical Proof:

Let B(n) give the count of binary sequences of length n without adjacent 1's.

B(0) = 1 //There is exactly one way to list 0 items.

B(1) = 2 //It's either a 0 or a 1.

Now consider the addition of an nth digit.
If the nth digit is 0, it may be follow any legal sequence of length (n-1)
If the nth digit is 1, then the (n-1)th digit must be a 0. These sequences can all be obtained by taking every sequence of length (n-2) and appending a 0.

Therefore: B(n) = B(n-1) + B(n-2)